# Java EE, injecting one EJB into another EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I've encountered one issue I can't seem to figure out. I would like to inject one EJB into another like this:

```
@Stateless
public class MainEJB {

    @EJB
    private HelperEJB helper;

}

@Stateless
public class HelperEJB implements HelperInterface {

}
```

As you can see, HelperEJB is exposed through a no-interface view (note: `HelperInterface` is an interface from an external library, it is not an EJB interface). This does not work, and I will get the following exception:

```
 javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'org.mycompany.ejb.HelperEJB #org.mycompany.ejb.HelperEJB'
```

However, if `HelperEJB` does not implement any interface:

```
@Stateless
public class HelperEJB {

}
```

It will work. It will also work if I have a `@Local` interface standing between MainEJB and HelperEJB.

Why this cannot be done through a no-interface view like in my first attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example should work if your private field is declared using the interface, like this:

```
@Stateless
public class MainEJB {
    @EJB
    private HelperInterface helper; // changed this
}

@Stateless
public class HelperEJB implements HelperInterface {
}

@Local
public interface HelperInterface {
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work. Why is that so? If a another EJB is injected through a no-interface view, it *must* be referenced by one of its interfaces if it implements any?

Comment: @Dario Just like Arjan Tijms said in his post.

Answer (score 2):

A no-interface view is only created when the EJB does not implement any (business) interface.

You can explicitly declare that you want a no-interface view by using the [@LocalBean](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/LocalBean.html) annotation.